# Illustrator Script Mass PDF export bleed

Tags: adobe-illustrator

im using a Savescript for a mass pdf export of multiple AI files.

The exports goes ok, except for the fact that it keeps on exporting with bleeds
(standard 3mm bleed)

this is the script: http://xcorr.net/2010/05/12/batch-export-ai-files-to-pdf/

with these saveoptios

```
function getPDFOptions()
{

    var pdfSaveOpts = new PDFSaveOptions();


    pdfSaveOpts.acrobatLayers = false;
    pdfSaveOpts.colorBars = false;
    pdfSaveOpts.colorCompression = CompressionQuality.AUTOMATICJPEGHIGH;
    pdfSaveOpts.compressArt = true; //default
    pdfSaveOpts.embedICCProfile = true;
    pdfSaveOpts.enablePlainText = true;
    pdfSaveOpts.generateThumbnails = true; // default
    pdfSaveOpts.optimization = true;
    pdfSaveOpts.pageInformation = false;
    pdfSaveOpts.preserveEditability = false;
    pdfSaveOpts.bleedLink = false;                                   
    pdfSaveOpts.bleedOffsetRect = [0,0,0,0];                             
    pdfSaveOpts.trimMarks  = false;   
    pdfSaveOpts.offset = 0.0; 

    return pdfSaveOpts;
}
```

---

i tried  `pdfSaveOpts.bleedLink = false;`  putting it on true with combination of  `pdfSaveOpts.bleedOffsetRect = [0,0,0,0];`   but for some reason it isn't working.

Does anyone see what i'm doing wrong or have a working script?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting up a pdf save preset in illustrator then specify it be used in the script with `pdfSaveOpts.pDFPreset = "presetName"`.
You could likely skip all of the other options, no need to reinvent the wheel if it will let you use a preset. You can read about all the options you can pass here [Illustrator scripting reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/illustrator/sdk/CC2015/Illustrator%20Scripting%20Reference%20-%20JavaScript.pdf).
Just search for PDFSaveOptions.

Answer (score 1):

The trim lines are there, they are just invisible due to the option:

`pdfSaveOpts.preserveEditability = false`

If you change this to `true` then you will see the bleeds in Illustrator again.

It's strange, but ran into this issue myself today.  This is the same thing that happens when exporting directly from Illustrator, and unchecking `Preserve Editability`. I believe the bleeds are encoded in the file, but you just can no longer see them.